# Regex routing with Iron-router

Tags: javascript, regex, meteor, routes, iron-router

I'm trying to write a route with iron-router for meteor to catch all requests to:

- /game/Quarterfinal3
- /game/Semifinal5
- /game/Grandfinal1

etc.
This is what i tried, but it doesn't work...

```
Router.route('final', {path: "(\\/)(game)(\\/).*?(final)(\\d)"}, function() {
  console.log("final");
  this.render('notStartedGame');
});
```

How do I solve this?

Comment: Excuse any mistake because I never worked with meteor neither iron router as well, but according to their docs: [`Iron Router now uses path-to-regexp`](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router#catchall-routes) so, in [path-to-regexp](https://github.com/pillarjs/path-to-regexp#named-parameters) docs you could use something like `/:game/.*(final)\d+`.. just a blind shot.

Comment: Adding my 2 cents : the new syntax of `Router.route` takes the path as first parameter and you can optionally provide a `name` option, which is the contrary of the previous behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need regex in your path as long as you use `:pathParam` format on your paths and it will be available within `this.params.pathParam`, namely:

if you are trying to catch those three routes:

```
Router.route('/game/:gameName', function() {
  var acceptablePaths = ["Quarterfinal3", "Semifinal5", "Grandfinal1"],
      gameName = this.params.gameName;
  // check if the game name is one of those that we are looking for
  if ( _.contains(acceptablePath, gameName) ) this.render("notStartedGame");
  // otherwise render a not found template or if you want do something else
  this.render("gameNotFound"); //assuming you have such a template
});
```

or if you are looking for any route that contains "final" in it:

```
Router.route('/game/:gameName', function() {
  var checkFor = "final",
      gameName = this.params.gameName;
  // check if the game name includes "final"
  if ( gameName.indexOf(checkFor) > -1 ) this.render("notStartedGame");
  // otherwise render a not found template or if you want do something else
  this.render("gameNotFound"); //assuming you have such a template
});
```

Comment: Works very well! Used the else part to render different games depending on a given game-ID at /game/:id :) Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

For future reference (since Meteor can do exactly what you've asked for), [DontVoteMeDown comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26844646/regex-routing-with-iron-router?newreg=07915af8c1ee4d8d9fd2a678fadd5a98#comment42253067_26844646) was right on the spot.

The following route has a fixed part `/game`, followed by a named parameter `/:gameName` based on the regex `.*final\d+`.

```
Router.route('/game/:gameName(.*final\\d+)', function() {
      console.log(this.params.gameName);
})
```

Nice things to note:

- You don't have to use one *regex* on the whole path. You can use multiple, localized *regexes* intertwined with fixed parts e.g: `/fix1/(.*)/fix2/:reg2(.*)/`. Check out the very nice [path-to-regexp documentation](https://github.com/pillarjs/path-to-regexp).
- You don't have to worry about the paths that do not fit the *regex* - they won't be routed here at all.
- Remember to escape your *regexes* correctly (e.g. note the double backslash)